# Does NHibernate override mapped setters?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to do this in an NHibernate mapped object:

```
    private ShiftTradeOffer m_Offer;

    public virtual ShiftTradeOffer Offer{ 
        get {
            return m_Offer;
        }
        set {

            //... Do some stuff ...

            if (condition)
            {
                m_Offer = value;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("whoops!");
            }

        }
    }
```

(ShiftTradeOffer being a mapped property)

1) Will this sort of thing pose a problem?

2) Is this setter invoked when the object is created?

3) Is this against best practices, in terms of enforcing validation? I would like to have object-specific behavior embedded in this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Properties should, by definition, never throw exceptions. Your approach violates this best practice.

**2)** The original setter is invoked because NHibernate just creates a proxy which calls the underlying getter/setter.
We use properties containing serialization logic to map serialized data which would not work otherwise.

Example:

```
public virtual List<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
public virtual string SerializedFoos 
{
    get { return JsonConvert.Serialize(Foos); }
    set { Foos = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Foo>>(value); }
}
```

Only the `SerializedFoos` Property is mapped and the domain code works with `Foos` Properties. So NHibernate writes nice JSON to the database while the domain can work with a handy List without taking a performance hit because (de)serialization only takes place when the object is loaded/saved.

**3)** There are many practices to validate, some prefer Attributes, some prefer a validation class per domain object.

I would go with the latter one because it's most flexible and you don't mess up your data object and you can easily validate the whole object.

One search term for the attribute way is "data annotations". Google brought up this result for example: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

If you do databinding you may take a look at the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful direction. I'm glad I asked. Is it still valid to limit what can be assigned in the property?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to add validation logic to your setter however you should consider what are the requirements for your validation technique. Often you will have to validate property values in dependency to others (i.e. startdate < enddate). Placing object wide validation into setters may cause problems.

Comment: I wonder what your reasons are for not throwing exceptions in setters. Microsoft has good guidelines for validation in property setters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property
They mention exceptions are certainly allowed in setters (avoid in getters!). Also, you should allow an instance to be in an invalid state and NOT check dependent properties.